# Как в Kotlin работать с функцией по ссылке, например, создавать массив из функций?

Tags: kotlin

Хотелось бы сделать что-то вроде этого

```
fun x()
{
    print("x")
}

fun y()
{
    print("у")
}


fun main() {
 
    var z = arrayListOf(x, y)
    
    for(n in z)
        n()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [оператор `::`](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references):

```kotlin
var z = arrayListOf(::x, ::y);
```

Answer (score 2):

Определите ваши функции как лямбды

```
val x = {
    print("x")
}

val y = {
    print("у")
}
```

И ваш остальной код будет валидный.